# Python - Join Two List Object Eachother If Their First Name Uppercase

Tags: python, list, capitalization

Is it possible to group Uppercased words which are sequential ?

For example i have a list like that:

```
lst =[['John'],['is'],['smart'],[','],['John'],['Kenneddy'],['is'],['smarter'],[','],['John'],['Fitzgerald'],['Kennedy'],['is'],['best']]
```

Desired Output:

```
[['John'],['is'],['smart'],[','],['John','Kenneddy'],['is'],['smarter'],[','],['John','Fitzgerald','Kennedy'],['is'],['best']]
```

Comment: I do not see difference between your input and output

Comment: basically first list contains tokenized words i want to group some uppercased sequentail array members which should count one

Comment: look at names in my output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can utilize [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the words by starting letter:

```
from itertools import groupby

d = [['John'],['is'],['smart'],[','],['John'],['Kenneddy'],['is'],[','],['John'],['Fitzgerald'],['Kennedy'],['is'],['best']]

sum(([[x[0] for x in g]] if k else list(g)
     for k, g in groupby(d, key=lambda x: x[0][0].isupper())),
    [])
```

Comment: Thank you so much worked lika a charm. Exactly what i want

Comment: it's a nice solution! But do you know how to make working `list(g)` under Python 3 - it throws `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`?

Comment: @MaxU: If you copy and paste the solution as such it should work on Python 3, I tested with 3.5 and it produces exactly the same result. Can you check that the initial variable is not named as `list` as in question but something else, like `d` in my example? That's exactly the reason I changed the original name of the variable so that it wouldn't hide builtin `list`.

Answer (score 0):

list =[['John'],['is'],['smart'],[','],['John'],['Kenneddy'],['is'],['smarter'],[','],['John'],['Fitzgerald'],['Kennedy'],['is'],['best']]

```
  upperlist=[]
   tmp = 0
   for l in list:
        if l[0][0].isupper():
         if tmp != 0 and list[tmp-1] != ",":
            u =list[tmp-1]+l
            print(u)
            if u[0] == ',':
              if l not in upperlist:
               upperlist.append(l)
            else:

                  upperlist.append(u)
         else:

              upperlist.append(l)
        else:

            upperlist.append(l)
        tmp = tmp+1

print(upperlist)
```

Comment: good job here thanks but out put is: [['John'], ['is'], ['smart'], [','], ['John'], ['John', 'Kenneddy'], ['is'], ['smarter'], [','], ['John'], ['John', 'Fitzgerald'], ['Fitzgerald', 'Kennedy'], ['is'], ['best']]  . Can you  remove the excessive words ?